# VirtualHost Apache Issues - Subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

This is starting to drive me insane and I'm sure it's easilly fixed and I'm just missing something.

I have ISPConfig 3 setup on a server, and I'm tweaking some of the apache config files to try and get the following setup:

- dbadmin.pixelfolio.co.uk - this to show phpmyadmin
- panel.pixelfolio.co.uk - this to show the ISPConfig panel
- www.pixelfolio.co.uk to show a client folder
- pixelfolio.co.uk to show the same client folder as above

I have A DNS records pointing to the same IP for all of these.

In my current setup everything is showing the current pages except for pixelfolio.co.uk (no www) which for some reason shows phpmyadmin. If I comment out the phpmyadmin vhost it shows the ISPConfig panel! I want it to show the same thing as www.pixelfolio.co.uk

**apache/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf**

```
#Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_value include_path .
        </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName pixelfolio.co.uk
        ServerAlias dbadmin.pixelfolio.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

**apache/sites-available/ispconfig.vhost**

```
######################################################
# This virtual host contains the configuration
# for the ISPConfig controlpanel
######################################################

# Listen 8080
#NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName pixelfolio.co.uk
  ServerAlias panel.pixelfolio.co.uk

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ispconfig/
    SuexecUserGroup ispconfig ispconfig
    <Directory /var/www/ispconfig/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI
      AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes Limit Options FileInfo
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/ispconfig/.php-fcgi-starter .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web/
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    <Directory /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
          php_value magic_quotes_gpc        0
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

  <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine Off
  </IfModule>

  # SSL Configuration
 # SSLEngine On
 # SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.crt
 # SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.key

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/php-cgi-scripts>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    </Directory>
```

**apache/sites-available/pixelfolio.co.uk.vhost**

```
<Directory /var/www/pixelfolio.co.uk>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/pixelfolio.co.uk/web

    ServerName pixelfolio.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.pixelfolio.co.uk pixelfolio.co.uk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@pixelfolio.co.uk

    ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/pixelfolio.co.uk/error.log

    Alias /error/ "/var/www/pixelfolio.co.uk/web/error/"
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/pixelfolio.co.uk/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

     # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    # php as fast-cgi enabled
        # For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        IdleTimeout 300
        ProcessLifeTime 3600
        # MaxProcessCount 1000
        DefaultMinClassProcessCount 0
        DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 100
        IPCConnectTimeout 3
        IPCCommTimeout 360
        BusyTimeout 300
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /var/www/pixelfolio.co.uk/web>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    # add support for apache mpm_itk
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
      AssignUserId web1 client1
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
          # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
      <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/webdav>
            <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
          SetHandler None
        </FilesMatch>
      </Directory>
      DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp/DavLock
      # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
      # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
      # WEBDAV BEGIN
      # WEBDAV END
    </IfModule>


</VirtualHost>
```

**apache/sites-available/default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServerName` is the canonical name for the virtualhost it's in; you should *not* put `pixelfolio.co.uk` in each VirtualHost. If you have only one name for a virtualhost, you do not need any `ServerAlias`.

In your case, you should have:

```
ServerName dbadmin.pixelfolio.co.uk
```

in the config file for PHPMyAdmin,

```
ServerName panel.pixelfolio.co.uk
```

in the config file for ISPConfig, and so on.

In the configuration file for the main website, you should have:

```
ServerName www.pixelfolio.co.uk
ServerAlias pixelfolio.co.uk
```

I hope this clears it up!

Comment: This does obviously make complete sense now!